# How to restrict access to the most direct base class, while still exposing the base-base classes?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy similar to this:

```
class Widget {
    // a lot of virtual members
};

class Button : public Widget {
    // new stuff + overrides
};

class MySuperButton : public Button {
    // ...
};
```

And I would like to hide the fact that `MySuperButton` inherit from `Button`, but not from `Widget`. Basically making the inheritance from `Button` private while keeping all its base classes public.

#### Why?

I have a complicated widget build on `Button`, which needs to maintain some invariant with its button state. Exposing it has a `Button` might allow something to
modify the button directly breaking these invariants.

Example:

```
MySuperButton button;
button.setText("Click me!") // calls Button::setText
// Oh no, MySuperButton set some special text which has now been overriden =(
```

#### What doesn't work

- Making `MySuperButton` inherit from `Button` privately also hides `Widget`, preventing me from doing `Widget` things with my button.
- Using access specifiers does not prevent `MySuperButton` to be converted into a `Button`.
  So `void doButtonStuff(Button& b);` will accept a `MySuperButton&` just fine.
- Using compositon forces me to reimplement a bunch of stuff that `Button` already reinmplements, just to forward it which is a PITA. Especially since the actual hierarchy is rather deep and these are big classes.
- Virtual inheritance doesn't seem to work as the base isn't visible (not sure why that would be a problem though). [See Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jv3Y9E73n)

I can not modify the `Button` or `Widget` classes as they are from an external library (Qt in this case). Also the actual code is somewhat more complicated, the provided hierarchy is for illustration.

Is there any way to do this, or do I need to accept that my widget can be broken if I am not careful ?

Comment: you should accept that your class hierarchy is not sound ;). Why not `class SuperButton : public Widget, private Button` ? or simply making the button a member?

Comment: I see virtual inheritance, or composition as solution.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `class SuperButton : public Widget, private Button` does something different (it inherit from `Widget` twice, once publicly and once privately). 
Making the button a member - AKA. composition - is not really viable for the reason described in the post.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would like to avoid composition if possible. Virtual inheritance was my first though, but in this case it doesn't compile because Widget is not visible [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/jv3Y9E73n)

Comment: You miss one `virtual` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1bfjWT6Ks).

Comment: @Jarod42 That would be a nice solution! Sadly I do not have access to the Button class (It's a Qt class in this case). I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: What operations specifically are you referring to by "expose the base-base class"?  If you want a consumer to be able to add your object to a collection of `Widget*` and invoke Widget virtual member functions polymorphically, that's easy enough: `class MySuperButton: private Button { public: Widget* asWidget() { return this; } };`  If you need polymorphic up-conversion and down-conversion using cast syntax, that's more problematic.

Comment: If you're worried about users of your class treating it like a button, then your class isn't a button and therefore shouldn't inherit from button.

Comment: @Taekahn I agree that from a strict OOP point of view, this object isn't a button. But, from a "I want this code to work" perspective, this class function as a button internally so I would like to reuse what I can from the existing class. **This point also stands for private inheritance in general**, I am just in a special case where I would like to expose only part of the hierarchy.

Comment: @gan_ private inheritance is a syntactic shortcut for composition. It does not model true inheritance, despite the name. I would suggest inheriting from widget and expose what you what from a contained button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not really possible.

A possible Qt-specific solution is the following:

```
class MySuperButton : public Widget {
public:
    MySuperButton () {
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(button = new Button());
        setLayout(layout);
    }

private:
    Button *button;
}
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't solve my problem (Since widget operations on the `MySuperButton` won't be applied to the button itself, but just knowing it isn't possible is an answer.

Comment: What kind of operations do you want to perform on `MySuperButton`? F.ex. hiding the `MySuperButton` will also hide the `Button` itself.